# When should I split a pallet in two or more?

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template, loose-coupling, tight-coupling

I've recently posted a question about this topic, but I want to make it more general, as people might have the same issue as me.

I've checked some substrate based repositories like [subsocial](https://github.com/dappforce/subsocial-node/tree/master/pallets) or [debio](https://github.com/debionetwork/debio-node/tree/main/pallets), and I was wondering when should I create a different pallet to model certain behaviour. For example, let's say I have a pallet composed of two items somewhat related:

```rs
pub struct Item1 {
   pub id: u32,
   pub value: u32,
}

pub struct Item1_History {
   pub item1_id: u32,
   pub values: Vec<u32>,
}

/// Pallet storage
#[pallet::storage]
pub(super) type Items1<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Twox64Concat, u32, Item1<T>>;

#[pallet::storage]
pub(super) type Items2<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Twox64Concat, u32, Item2<T>>;
```

When creating an `item` of type `Item1`, I want to also generate another `item` of type `Item2`. This `Item2` stores a vector of values, and if a new value is inserted, then it should also update the `Item1` with the latest value.

```rs
#[pallet::call]
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
   #[pallet::weight(0)]
   pub fn create_item1(origin: OriginFor<T>, id: u32, value: u32) -> DispatchResult {
      let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
      <Items1<T>>::insert(&id, Item1 {id, value});

      // Create new vector with the first value provided
      let mut values = Vec::new();
      values.push(value);
      <items2<T>>::insert(&id, Item2 {id, values};
   }

   #[pallet::weight(0)]
   pub fn add_new_value_to_item2(origin: OriginFor<T>, id: u32, new_value: u32) -> DispatchResult {
      let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
      // Get the item2 and push a new value
      let mut item2 = <Items2<T>>::get(id).ok_or(<AnyError>);
      item2.values.push(new_value);
      <Items2<T>>::insert(id, item2);
      
      // Get the item1 and update the value
      let mut item = <Items1<T>>::get(id).ok_or(<AnyError>);
      item.value = new_value;
      <Items1<T>>::insert(id, item);
   }
}
```

Can this logic be split into two pallets? or because both items interact in a close way it's better to keep them both on the same pallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question that is hard to give a specific answer to.

In general, splitting up pallets is useful when you expect the pallets to be modular, reusable, and potentially interchangeable.

In the case you are developing some specific logic for your blockchain, creating a single pallet will probably be easier in every way.

However, if you plan to create a pallet which you want to share with the community, the more monolithic it is, the less likely it will be used.